# Lowest month won't show up

Tags: c++

Write a program that lets the user enter the total rainfall for each of 12 months (starting with January) into an array of doubles.

I'm a beginner and I'm having trouble getting the lowest month to display, but the highest month displays.

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int num_months = 12;
    double rainfall[num_months];
    double total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    double least = rainfall[0];
    double high = rainfall[0];
    string highest_month;
    string lowest_month;
    double high_num;
    double low_num;
    string months[num_months] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    for (int count = 0; count < num_months; count++) {
        cout << "Enter rainfall for " << months[count] << ":";
        cin >> rainfall[count];
        while (rainfall[count] < 0) {
            cout << "invalid data(negative rainfall) --retry" << endl;
            cin >> rainfall[count];
        }
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < num_months; count++)
        total += rainfall[count];
    average = total / 12;

    high_num = rainfall[0];
    low_num = rainfall[0];
    for (int count = 0; count < num_months; count++) {
        if (rainfall[count] < low_num) {

            lowest_month = months[count];
            low_num = rainfall[count];
        }
    }
    for (int count = 0; count < num_months; count++) {
        if (rainfall[count] > high_num) {
            highest_month = months[count];
            high_num = rainfall[count];
        }
    }

    cout << "Total rainfall: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Average rainfall: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Least rainfall in: " << lowest_month << endl;
    cout << "Most rainfall in: " << highest_month << endl;
}
```

Comment: Does the error only happen when January has the least rainfall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to give `highest_month` and `lowest_month` an initial value, so they remains empty when the first month has highest or lowest rainfall.

Give them initial values to fix:

```
high_num = rainfall[0];
low_num = rainfall[0];
highest_month = months[0]; // add this
lowest_month = months[0]; // add this
```

Another way is adding some value to the initial values of `high_num` and `low_num` so that there must be updates in the loops.

```
high_num = rainfall[0] - 1; // at least rainfall[0] is higher than this
low_num = rainfall[0] + 1; // at least rainfall[0] is lower than this
```